# Acapela TTS engine: "Undefined symbols" in XCode for all classes

Tags: ios, xcode4, linker-errors, text-to-speech

I'm trying to get started with the Acapela TTS engine for iPhone. I'm using XCode 4 and I've been following these instructions for setup:

http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com/documentation-quick-start-how-to-add-tts-in-your-app

I've added the voice, and added all the necessary files (from the `api` and `license` folders) to a group called "TTS", added them to my project's target, and imported them into one of my view controllers in the same manner as the tutorial. However, when I build I get this message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AcapelaLicense", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NavigationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AcapelaSpeech", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NavigationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AcapelaSetup.o
  "_AcapelaVoiceName", referenced from:
      -[AcapelaSetup SetCurrentVoice:] in AcapelaSetup.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There are no errors for the files not being found, and when I cmd+click on on the `#import` statements it takes me to the relevant source code files. So how come XCode thinks the symbols are undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the files libBabTTS.a and libMobilityStatic.a to your project?

Comment: Bingo... sorry I didn't put it as an answer. It's all working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess : You may check the visibility of headers on your projects build phase.

Comment: Where on the build phases screen are the headers? In the 'compile sources' phase it just contains source files, no header files.

Comment: If you don't have copied headers you won't have the section, use the (+) button (bottom left) and add copy header to build phase.

Comment: Just tried that, still getting the same message. I can't see how it's not finding it!

Comment: Are you adding an xCode project or a static library ?

Comment: I'm just adding some `.h` and `.m` files, following the instructions in the linked tutorial.

Comment: Are you sure your files are located inside the project directory ?

Comment: Yeah - they're all in there with the rest of my source files.

Comment: try removing every thing on your project and adding everything back. it helps some times